# encodings again

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to work with sqlite on python:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
con = sqlite.connect('/home/argon/super.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from notes')
for i in cur.fetchall():
    print i[2]
```

And I sometimes get something like this (I am from Russia):

```
&#208;&#158;&#209;&#130;&#208;&#178;&#208;&#181;&#209;&#130; etc...
```

And if I pass this string to this function(it helped me in other projects):

```
def unescape(text):
    def fixup(m):
        text = m.group(0)
        if text[:2] == "&#":
            # character reference
            try:
                if text[:3] == "&#x":
                    return unichr(int(text[3:-1], 16))
                else:
                    return unichr(int(text[2:-1]))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        else:
            # named entity
            try:
                text = unichr(htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint[text[1:-1]])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return text # leave as is
    return re.sub("&#?\w+;", fixup, text)
```

I get even more weird result:

```
ÐÑÐ²ÐµÑÐ¸ÑÑ Ñ ÑÐ¸ÑÐ¸ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸ÐµÐ¼ etc
```

What should I do to get normal Cyrillic symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&#208;&#158;` looks like a UTF-8 byte pair for `\xD0\x9E`, or `\u1054`. Better known as the cyrillic character `О` (Capital O).

In other words, you have strangely encoded UTF-8 data on your hand. Turn the `&#123;` digits into bytes (`chr(208)` would do) then decode from UTF-8:

```
>>> (chr(208) + chr(158)).decode('utf-8')
u'\u1054'
>>> print (chr(208) + chr(158)).decode('utf-8')
О
>>> print (chr(208) + chr(158) + chr(209) + chr(130) + chr(208) + chr(178)).decode('utf-8')
Отв
```